# Dynamic tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

I am trying to develop a tooltip using dynamically populated string appended to my html file. I manage to print out the string with an alert box but it does not seem to show up when I am trying to use it as tooltip even though the string is appended to the html file but not showing. Find my code below
hmtl:

```js
function handler(ev){
 var counter = 0;
 var target = $(ev.target);
 var id= target.attr('id');
 function check(ev){
        var moteJson = [{"mote_id":101, "location": "qwert", "platform":"x1"}, {"mote_id":102, "location": "qwert", "platform":"x2"}, {"mote_id":103, "location": "qwert", "platform":"x3"}]; 
  if (counter<1){
   var target = $(ev.target);
   var id= target.attr('id');
   if (target.is(".button")) {
    for (i=0; i<moteJson.length; i++){
     if (moteJson[i].mote_id == id){
      var display = "<div class = 'info'><p>Mote_id:  " +moteJson[i].mote_id + "\nLocation:  " + moteJson[i].location + "\nPlatform:  " + moteJson[i].platform + "</p></div>";
      $("#"+id ).html(display);
      
     }  
    }
   }
  }
 counter++;
 }
  $(".button").mouseleave(check);
}
```

```css
.button.info{
 visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.button.info::after {
 content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.button:hover .info {
 visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#GFDisplay"><input type="button" value="104" name="104" id="104" class="button" onmouseover="handler(this)" style="position: absolute; left: 40px; top: 40px; background-color: green;"></a>
```

Comment: Your JS has an error. Make sure you give us a working [mcve] `"Uncaught ReferenceError: moteJson is not defined"`

Comment: Should be fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mostly CSS related. You're using the wrong selectors, like `.button.info` needs a space... but you're appending `.info` to your `input`. You should put `.info` after the `input` and use an adjacent sibling selector in your CSS. I also rewrote your jQuery to be a little more efficient and only create the `.info` box once.

```js
function handler(el) {
  var target = $(el);
  var id = target.attr("id");
  if (target.is(".button")) {
    if (!target.siblings(".info").length) {
      var display = $("<div class = 'info'><p>Mote_id:</p></div>");
      target.after(display);
      var t = setTimeout(function() {
        display.addClass('show');
      },50)
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.info {
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.button + .info::after {
 content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.button:hover + .info.show {
    opacity: 1;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="tooltip" href="#GFDisplay"><input type="button" value="104" name="104" id="104" class="button" onmouseover="handler(this)" style="position: absolute; left: 40px; top: 40px; background-color: green;"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is mostly working but I will fix the kink for myself

Comment: How would you do to get the text to each buttons (i have several of them) as at the moment is only displaying in the top left corner from my display?

Comment: @AlexAcquier add `.tooltip` to the `a` that wraps the `.button`.

Comment: I am not sure how to show it to you, I have manged to move it through CSS but for every button it displays the required data but in one single location when i would like to have near the input buttons

Comment: @AlexAcquier can you create a codepen.io or jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: Well, I will try to fix it myself if no good comes of it I try codepen or jsfiddle